# Not able to marshal json.RawMessage while []byte works fine

Tags: json, go, marshalling

A reproducible example can be found here https://go.dev/play/p/wNyhezDfxVt

I want to marshal (`json.Marshal(...)`) a struct with `json.RawMessage` fields.

```golang
type Container1 struct {
    OldValue json.RawMessage `json:"old"`
    NewValue json.RawMessage `json:"new"`
}
```

However, it complains about the below error:

```
error calling MarshalJSON for type json.RawMessage: invalid character 'h' looking for beginning of value
```

Changing `json.RawMessage` to `[]byte` fix the issue, but note that `json.RawMessage` is nothing but `[]byte`:

```golang
// RawMessage is a raw encoded JSON value.
// It implements Marshaler and Unmarshaler and can
// be used to delay JSON decoding or precompute a JSON encoding.
type RawMessage []byte
```

I want to be still able to use `json.RawMessage`, any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The type `json.RawMessage` is expected to hold valid JSON, because it will be serialized as-is (raw).

When you initialize a `json.RawMessage` field with `[]byte("hello")`, you're converting to `[]byte`, the string literal `"hello"`, whose content is `hello` **without quotes**. Then `json.Marshal` fails, because you need the quotes `"` for it to be a valid JSON string. To keep the quotes, you have to use an unescaped string literal enclosed in backticks.

Changing the initialization of your struct to this will work:

```
    c1 := Container1{
        []byte(`"hello"`),
        []byte(`"world"`),
    }
```

The `[]byte` slice in `Container2` instead doesn’t cause errors despite holding the same byte content simply because [`json.Marshal` defaults to serializing byte slices as base64.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089750/marshal-byte-to-json-giving-a-strange-string)

As a matter of fact, after fixing your playground, the two output JSON look different:

From `json.RawMessage`:

```
{"old":"hello","new":"world"}
```

From `[]byte`:

```
{"old":"aGVsbG8=","new":"d29ybGQ="}
```

Comment: do you mind sharing the new playground link?

Comment: @0xbe1 here you go https://go.dev/play/p/UNJ0ixKs7uq